# Django session delete json object

Tags: json, django, session

How can I remove object from session which has 'pk':50 and store it for all pages. I added SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST=True to Settings.py and request.session.modified = True to just above line when I modify request session, but there was no effect.

Json looks like

```
[
{
    "pk": 50, 
    "model": "notifications.notification", 
    "fields": {
        "recipient": 81, 
        "verb": "commented", 
        "emailed": false, 
        "action_object_object_id": "", 
        "level": "info", 
        "deleted": false, 
        "timestamp": "2017-01-25T11:18:53.197Z", 
        "target_content_type": null, 
        "actor_object_id": "1", 
        "action_object_content_type": null, 
        "target_object_id": "790", 
        "actor_content_type": 3, 
        "unread": true, 
        "data": "\"\"", 
        "public": true, 
        "description": "commented on your request"
    }
}, 
{
    "pk": 38, 
    "model": "notifications.notification", 
    "fields": {
        "recipient": 81, 
        "verb": "commented", 
        "emailed": false, 
        "action_object_object_id": "", 
        "level": "info", 
        "deleted": false, 
        "timestamp": "2017-01-24T12:23:08Z", 
        "target_content_type": null, 
        "actor_object_id": "1", 
        "action_object_content_type": null, 
        "target_object_id": "790", 
        "actor_content_type": 3, 
        "unread": true, 
        "data": "\"\"", 
        "public": true, 
        "description": "commented on your request"
    }
}
]
```

## code

```
def setNotifRead(request, notif_id):
    notifObject = Notification.objects.filter(pk=notif_id)
    notifObject.update(unread=0)
    notifications = request.session['notifications']
    request.session.modified = True
    del notifications[notif_id] # Something should be done here
    return
```

Comment: I don't see the point of showing us the JSON data. You should be showing the code of the view.

Comment: code has been added, I know I have to find a index of the object where pk=50 and then I can easily remove this session.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through the data and filter the items that don't have the relevant ID.

```
notifications = [item for item in request.session['notifications'] if item['id'] != notif_id
request.session['notifications'] = notifications
```